# To setup cron for IOS script in MAC

Tags: ios

I have a IOS stimulator created in MAC. So for our project testing i need to run the test for every 15mins. Can someone help me create a Cron job for this?

The command i enter to run IOS script is cd /Users/Downloads/uiautomation/ ./runthis.sh

Answer (score 1):

The cron syntax is:

```
# +---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
# |  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |  |  |  |  |   
  *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
```

Issue this command `crontab -e` and put this `*/15 * * * * /path/to/script` in it. ***/15** means every 15 minutes...